# SQL Server 2008 R2: trigger after update

Tags: sql, triggers, sql-server-2008-r2

This is my first post so please bear with me.  Here are the tables I'm working with and I'm only showing the relevant columns:

**Movement**:

```
  id
  cnt_tare_weight
  chassis_tare_weight
```

**Stop**:

```
  movement_id
  order_id
```

For each movement record, there are 2 or more stop records. The way this works, is that we create an order and create the stops. The stops are grouped into movements.

Here's some example data:

**Movement**:

```
id       cnt_tare_weight      chassis_tare_weight
-------------------------------------------------
1545257  4525.2                3652.2
1545258  null                  null
```

**Stop**:

```
order_id     movement_id
------------------------
0933774      1545257
0933774      1545257
0933774      1545258
0933774      1545258
```

Here's what I am trying to accomplish:

When the `cnt_tare_weight` and/or `chassis_tare_weight` are updated in the `movement` record, I need to copy this data to all other movement records for that order. I want to use a trigger after update to do this.

Here is what I've come up with but and I'm not sure it will work. I would like to see if what I'm wanting do is correct or if I'm missing something.

Here's my SQL:

```
CREATE TRIGGER set_tare_weights
ON movement
AFTER UPDATE AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @movement_id AS INT;
    DECLARE @cnt_tare_weight AS DECIMAL(8,1);
    DECLARE @chz_tare_weight AS DECIMAL(8,1); 
    DECLARE @order_id AS int;

    SELECT @movement_id = inserted.id
    FROM INSERTED

    IF update(cnt_tare_weight)
    BEGIN
        SET @cnt_tare_weight = 'Updated cnt_tare_weight'
    END

    IF update(chz_tare_weight)
    BEGIN
        SET @chz_tare_weight = 'Updated chz_tare_weight'
    END

    SELECT @order_id = order_id
    FROM stop 
    WHERE movement_id = @movement_id

    UPDATE movement 
    SET cnt_tare_weight = @cnt_tare_weight, 
        chz_tare_weight = @chz_tare_weight 
    WHERE @movement_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT movement_id 
                           FROM stop 
                           WHERE order_id = @order_id) 
      AND id <> @movement_id
END
```

I have never created a SQL Server trigger before. I'm not sure if this will work or if I need to do something more. Do I need to create a trigger that calls a stored procedure? Or will the above work?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: So your problem is? or you want to have [codereview.se]?

Comment: @Alex [codereview.se] *requires* code that works as intended (see [a guide to CR for SO users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/5777/23788)). This isn't a CR question - it's just *too broad*. john4938, you need to test your code to see if it's going to work. When you *know* it works and then wonder if there wouldn't be better ways to do this, or other things to improve, *that*'s when you put it up on Code Review. Stack Overflow is about *specific* coding issues (see [mcve] and [ask]).